# LineChart Broken Line With DateTimeAxis

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have a LineChart with a DateTimeAxis as horizontalAxis and a maximum set. If a point is beyond the maximum date, the whole segment will not appear. Yet, is there a way to make it appear until it reachs the border of the chart?

The code here :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Simple example to demonstrate the DateTimeAxis class. -->
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
     [Bindable]
     public var stockDataAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
         {date:new Date(2005,7,27), close: 32.71},
         {date:new Date(2005,7,29), close: 42.11},
         {date:new Date(2005,8,4), close: 102.99}]);
]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:Panel title="DateTimeAxis Example">
<mx:LineChart id="mychart" height="100%" width="100%"
  paddingRight="5" paddingLeft="5"
  showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{stockDataAC}">
<mx:horizontalAxis>
<mx:DateTimeAxis dataUnits="days"  maximum="{new Date(2005,8,2)}"/>
</mx:horizontalAxis>
<mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:LinearAxis baseAtZero="false" />
</mx:verticalAxis>
<mx:series>
    <mx:LineSeries yField="close" xField="date" displayName="AAPL"/>
</mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
</mx:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer on [flexcoders](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/flexcoders/message/161920) : Set filterData="false" on your LineSeries.